# Portrait to Landscape on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am building a ios app which is currently only support portrait mode. I want to convert into landscape mode only. but When I am trying to change my view its stick to the portrait mode only. I change the orientation in my nib file as well. But it didn't work. Can you please tell me which constrain is stopping it to view in portrait mode. and any one suggest me to forcefully convert into landscape mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The App's `Info.plist` file contains the applications default settings for which orientations the app will respond to. You can double-click it to edit it in Xcode and then set the keys easily there, or you can edit the plist source directly to do it.

From the [Information Property List Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html):

> ...For example, to specify a portrait launch orientation for iPhone
>   and iPod touch devices and a landscape-right launch orientation for
>   iPad, you should specify the corresponding keys in your Info.plist
>   file:

```
<key>UIInterfaceOrientation</key>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
<key>UIInterfaceOrientation~ipad</key>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
```

There is also a per-ViewController method you can override to determine if that particular view will orientate to the device orientation.

From the [UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/) documentation:

**Handling View Rotations**

> In iOS 8, all rotation-related methods are
>   deprecated. Instead, rotations are treated as a change in the size of
>   the view controller’s view and are therefore reported using the
>   `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` method. When the
>   interface orientation changes, UIKit calls this method on the window’s
>   root view controller. That view controller then notifies its child
>   view controllers, propagating the message throughout the view
>   controller hierarchy.
>
> In iOS 6 and iOS 7, your app supports the interface orientations
>   defined in your app’s Info.plist file. A view controller can override
>   the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method to limit the list of
>   supported orientations. Typically, the system calls this method only
>   on the root view controller of the window or a view controller
>   presented to fill the entire screen; child view controllers use the
>   portion of the window provided for them by their parent view
>   controller and no longer participate directly in decisions about what
>   rotations are supported. The intersection of the app's orientation
>   mask and the view controller's orientation mask is used to determine
>   which orientations a view controller can be rotated into.
>
> You can override the `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` for
>   a view controller that is intended to be presented full screen in a
>   specific orientation.

Comment: I try that my friends. but it didn't work. I tried with supportedInterfaceOrientations method as well but still it is same. I changed value in plist as well. So Is there anything else. I redesigned the view in landscape mode as well but its not appear in landscape mode. can you please tell me anyther way to solve it.

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout in Interface Builder, and did you set up constraints?  There are contstraints you can set called size class constraints that take effect during specific orientations that you could experiment with. Also consider overriding `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`  or `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator` to see if it's being called. If it isn't then that helps point to a problem at a higher level.

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot to put one line of code in my AppDelegate implementation. I just put that Line of code and now its perfectly fine.

Code is self.window.rootviewController = self.ViewController